# Jquery - Choppy animations in IE scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, internet-explorer

So I have a toolbar that is on the left side of my page that I have animating when the user scrolls to stay focused on the top of the page.  It works perfectly in every browser except IE.  In IE, it appears to almost do it twice.  It bounces around and is very strange.  This is my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(),
            toolbarLocation = toolbar.offset().top + toolbar.height(),
            canvasSize = formCanvas.offset().top + formCanvas.height();
        //Give toolbar a new position relative to container
        if ((toolbarLocation + windowScrollPosition) < canvasSize + toolbarLocation) {
            toolbar.animate({'margin-top': (windowScrollPosition - 95) <= 0 ? windowScrollPosition : (windowScrollPosition - 95) + 'px'}, 65);
        }

    });
```

any thoughts on how to fix this in IE?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want it to animate, i would use `position: fixed` to keep it there instead of animating it.  That would probably fix your problem at least.